# Encode HTML before sending to Controller/DB

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

`A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (Body="<b></b>").`

This error is occurring when I try to enter something like `<b></b>` in my comments field and send it. I've searched and only thing I find is to disable validation for dangerous data altogether, but I don't want to disable it since then my site will be vulnerable.
What I want is to encode it before sending or something along these lines so it will send the data, just encoded.

Comment: possible duplicate of [A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're using .net 4 you can decorate your model with [AllowHtml] which will let just that specific property through.  You can then sanitize it in the controller logic.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string prop1 { get; set; }

    [AllowHtml]
    public string prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: -1 OP stated he didn't want to disable or sidestep validation.  He's right to NOT want to do that - very bad security practice to disable validation.

Comment: @Tim Thats why I suggested a per property solution not per request and suggested that the value was sanitized at the controller

Comment: I missed that part when I first read your answer.  Sorry for the downvote.

Comment: Well this approach works with Microsoft AntiXSS libraries, but then if I want to show something in <pre></pre> (code) tags it just removes it. Maybe it is better idea to just do a replace on it like forums do? [b] will be replaced to <b> etc.. Since all I need is Bold/Italic/Underline/Link/Img/Code

Answer (score 8):

Why not simply use the HttpUtility.HtmlEncode method?

```
string encodedHTML = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(unencodedString)
```

You might also look into Microsoft's [Anti-XSS Library](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=325).

Comment: Tim, your answer lacks context completely. What are you trying to do with that `HtmlEncode`? `&lt;b&gt;&lt;/b&gt;` is NOT `<b></b>`. Storing the html encoded version in your database would be very wrong.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting (or at least that wasn't my intention) to store the encoded version in the database.  I was simply stating that taking unsanitized HTML as input is never a good idea.

Comment: What is wrong with posting an HTML string as long as it's properly encoded when you write it back to an HTML output?

Answer (score 0):

what about adding a javascript event on the submit button, which encodes the textvalues before sending the form?

try encodeURI or encodeUriComponent

Comment: User can just disable JS and input whatever he wants then.